# Stylesheets interpreted as cookies in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

Good morning,

I have the following problem: some elements of the webpage like .css and javascripts are treated as cookies in Internet Explorer(the webpage works fine  with Firefox and Chrome). Then these elements are blocked and they appeared in the websites blocked due to privacy issues.

If I visit the website using its IP address, it works well. However, If I use the domain, I have the problem with these elements. The website is accessed using a link from other website.

The website was developed using Icefaces.

I think that the cause of the problem is to have the main page and its link in different servers and with different names. I haven't had much permissions to modify server settings.

I haven't configured privacy policies(p3p) but I have already checked problems with domain names like underscores.

Could you please give some suggestions in how to solve the problem?. For me, it is not a proper solution just to lower the privacy settings to make IE accept the content.

Regards,